# Load into oracle table from cobol flat file with occurs times

Tags: oracle, load, cobol

Incoming file format mainframe/cobol record layout, one single record that is more than 21000 characters long. Please be aware of the occurs 350 times , which is making the record length very long, a horizontal layout, instead of a row-like layout in incoming file.

```
id  pic x(23).
  idnum  pic 9(04).
  filler pic x(10).
  grp  occurs 350 times
    grpkey1   PIC X(25).
    grpkeynum PIC X(09).
    grpsubkey PIC X(01).
    grptyp    PIC X(01).
    grpst     PIC X(08).
    grpend    PIC X(08).
    filler    PIC X(10).
```

Target Table Definition (Preferably Oracle External Table)

```
create table grpkeys (
id  CHAR(23),
idnum  CHAR(04),
filler10 CHAR(10),
grpkey1   CHAR(25),
grpkeynum CHAR(09),
grpsubkey CHAR(01),
grptyp    CHAR(01),
grpst     CHAR(08),
grpend    CHAR(08),
filler20    CHAR(10)
)
```

I have to load above record format in a file into a table (preferably a working oracle external table, if possible). id, idnum, filler10 values need to be copied into all 350 records created in oracle table (preferably external table) for a single record of incoming file. Please suggest the easiest way to accomplish this.

Comment: You said "mainframe/cobol" record layout. Does this mean that the file is on a mainframe, likely in EBCDIC encoding?
If yes: Do you want to transfer the file from the mainframe first or do you have access to oracle from the mainframe? Is this a one-time issue or something that will be done regularly?
If the data size does allow it I'd just create a new file with each sub-record split into one (and extended with the group header data) either by COBOL or via `sed`/`awk`/`perl`/pure shell script/whatever and use a simple external table definition.

Comment: [SQL*Loader](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e22490/ldr_concepts.htm#SUTIL003), a standard Oracle command-line utility, will be helpful to you here.

Comment: @jay-j please take [the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see how this site works - and delete the "non-answer" afterwards (maybe after moving some "response" to a comment here). As the shell script has nothing directly to do with this question it should be kept separate.

Comment: Hello Jay, there is a tool named [Cobrix](https://github.com/AbsaOSS/cobrix) which can help you load COBOL data using spark. When in spark, they are then represented by generic DataFrame which you can store anywhere you would like and spark is great in handling big loads of data.

Answer (score 0):

I'll stick to 5 columns for this example, but there should be no syntactic nor performance restriction to scale from 005 up to 350.  Example assumes your file is on Oracle database server in file `/tmp/test/test.txt`.

My recommendation is to use an Oracle external table definition that effectively reads the data file "as is" (in all its 350-column glory), but does not worry about parsing out the 350-repeat field into components like grpkey1, grpsubkey, etc.

```
CREATE DIRECTORY TEST_DIR AS '/tmp/test';

CREATE TABLE TEST_XT 
(
    id  VARCHAR2(23),
    idnum  INTEGER,
    filler10 VARCHAR2(10),
    GRP_001 varchar2(62),
    GRP_002 varchar2(62),
    GRP_003 varchar2(62),
    GRP_004 varchar2(62),
    GRP_005 varchar2(62)
)
ORGANIZATION EXTERNAL 
    (
    TYPE ORACLE_LOADER 
    DEFAULT DIRECTORY TEST_DIR
    ACCESS PARAMETERS 
        (
        RECORDS DELIMITED BY NEWLINE
        FIELDS
            (
                ID          CHAR(23),
                IDNUM       INTEGER EXTERNAL (4),
                FILLER10    CHAR(10),
                GRP_001 CHAR(62),
                GRP_002 CHAR(62),
                GRP_003 CHAR(62),
                GRP_004 CHAR(62),
                GRP_005 CHAR(62)
            )
        )
    LOCATION ('test.txt')
);
```

Then wrap that external table definition with a view definition that performs an UNPIVOT operation (plus some basic SUBSTR functions to slice each of the 350 unpivoted GRP fields into its constituent pieces).

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW TEST_V AS
SELECT  ID, IDNUM, FILLER10, GRP_NUM,
        SUBSTR(GRP_STR,01,25) GRPKEY1,
        SUBSTR(GRP_STR,26,09) GRPKEYNUM,
        SUBSTR(GRP_STR,35,01) GRPSUBKEY,
        SUBSTR(GRP_STR,36,01) GRPTYP,
        SUBSTR(GRP_STR,37,08) GRPST,
        SUBSTR(GRP_STR,45,08) GRPEND,
        SUBSTR(GRP_STR,53,10) FILLER20
FROM
    (        
    SELECT  * 
    FROM    TEST_XT
    UNPIVOT 
        (GRP_STR FOR GRP_NUM IN 
            (
            GRP_001 as 1,
            GRP_002 as 2,
            GRP_003 as 3,
            GRP_004 as 4,
            GRP_005 as 5
            )
        )
    );
```

Of course, you can query view directly, or load to standard table (`insert into standard_table select * from test_v`) for indexing, partitioning, etc needs.

Also, you can scale to desired level of performance by adding parallelism to external table:

```
ALTER TABLE TEST_XT PARALLEL 8;
```

Comment: Thanks Kevin. I was also exploring on similar thoughts. But, your example is awesome.